.net maui put a fixed partition on tabbar
I am trying to make a music application. I have a tabbar structure that I defined from Shell (not with xaml but with c#) and I change tabs with this section below. I want my music player to remain fixed on the tabbar even if I change the page, that is, the music player should not change even if I am not on the page. I have been looking for a solution for 1 week.
I tried many methods but none of them worked.
AppShell.xaml.cs:
       var tabBar = new TabBar();
           
           // Tabları oluştur
           var homeTab = new ShellContent
           {
               
               Title = "Home",
               Icon = "home.png",
               Content = new MainMenu()
           };

           var searchTab = new ShellContent
           {
               Title = "Search",
               Icon = "grid.png",
               Content = new Gözat()
           };

           var settingsTab = new ShellContent
           {
               Title = "Settings",
               Icon = "a20.png",
               Content = new ogebul(),
               
           };
var settingsTab2 = new ShellContent
           {
               Title = "Settings",
               Icon = "fff.png",
               Content = new arsiv()
           }; var settingsTab3 = new ShellContent
           {
               Title = "Settings",
               Icon = "diamond.png",
               Content = new Premium()
           };
           // Tabları tabBar'a ekle
           tabBar.Items.Add(homeTab);
           tabBar.Items.Add(searchTab);
           tabBar.Items.Add(settingsTab);
           tabBar.Items.Add(settingsTab2);
           tabBar.Items.Add(settingsTab3);
           // Shell'e tabBar'ı ekle
           Items.Add(tabBar);

I want it to be
I want this kind of structure, it should not change even if the tab changes. I tried using grid so far but it didn't work
    


May I know what platform you are targeting and the .NET version you are using?

Is it important for you to use the Shell TabBar at all? Or would it be an option to use a plain page, put buttons to navigate at the bottom, then above your player control, and above that a ContentView that is filled with your pages via the navigation buttons?

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I am using .Net MAUI 8 windows10.0.19041.0 and Android is my target platform but this problem is for Android, I will write different code for Windows

@TorbenSchramme It may be possible but honestly I don't understand how to do it. Can you show me the sample code, thank you for everything.

@SalihEtkaAkagündüz You can customize your shell Tabbar using Handler, see this sample link .

Since you're using Shell on your MAUI app and you want to place a fixed partition control above the TabBar, you may need Handlers to customize your shell Tabbar. You can create a custom control that inherits TabBar and then define your fixed partition control.

public partial class CustomTabBar : TabBar
{
   //define your fixed partition control 
    ...
}

Here's a sample: .NET MAUI Shell Customization, you can refer to it.
